# You would vs. you’d

Tags: punctuation

I’m wondering what is the correct punctuation in this sentence:

> My place works, unless you would/you’d like to have the meeting at your place.

Comment: "You'd" is the contraction of "you would".  Why do you think one is more "correct" than the other?

Comment: Well would I read “you’d” as “you would.? How would you comprehend it?

Comment: Yes, *you'd* is a contraction of *you would*, just like Andrew says.  That's exactly how a native speaker would interpret it.

Comment: In this sentence, no native speaker would read "you'd" as "you had".  "You had like" is not grammatical.  So they're exactly the same thing, although as with all contractions, *you'd* is slightly less formal.

Comment: Did you mean “you would” or were you addressing another contraction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either is grammatically correct, but "you'd" is also a contraction for "you had". Personally, I would use "you would".

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/you'd